# Python Easygui image file does not exist?

Tags: python, image, easygui

Whenever I try and run this code:

```
encounter1 = buttonbox(image = "source.gif", msg = "A goblin approaches!", choices = ["Attack", "Heal"])
```

It just says "image file source.gif does not exist". I am currently using Python 3.6.1 with the latest version of easygui. The image is also in the same folder as the .py file. Thanks.

Comment: How are you calling the script? Are you running the script from the folder with the source image?

Comment: Running the .py from inside the folder fixed the problem. duh... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to fix that problem:

1) Use script anywhere but use full path, like:**`"Path\\To\\Image"`**.

2) Use script in same place as photo.

:EDIT

**`2)`** is posted from other user in comments, so I just added **`1)`**.